# Is it possible to open Azure Storage Explorer using direct link with SAS token?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage, azure-storage-explorer

When i want to launch `Azure Storage Explorer` using direct link what i do is copy it from app and pasting to my browser. It looks somethig like that:

```
storageexplorer:// ... and there are subId, AccountId etc
```

[image]

My question is, is it possible to produce `uri` like above using SAS token to open concrete container from my web browser using `Azure Storage Explorer`?

Answer (score 1):

I'm from the Microsoft for Founders Hub team. With this connection method, you'll use a SAS URI for the required storage account. You'll need a SAS URI whether you want to use a file share, table, queue, or blob container. You can get a SAS URI either from the Azure portal or from Storage Explorer.
To add a SAS connection:

1. Open Storage Explorer.
2. Connect to your Azure storage account.
3. Select the connection type: shared access signature (SAS) URI.
4. Provide a meaningful name for the connection.
5. When you're prompted, provide the SAS URI.
6. Review and verify the connection details, and then select Connect.

When you've added a connection, it appears in the resource tree as a new node. You'll find the connection node in this branch: Local & attached > Storage Accounts > Attached Container > Service.

Comment: This will not result in a direct link with a storageexplorer:// scheme but merely describes how to connect with a SAS token.